# React, Django: How do I manage a session after a user changes their password?

Tags: reactjs, django, session-cookies, sessionid, csrf-token

I am developing an administration panel in `React` with `Django` for user management, amongst other actions.

`Django` takes care of ORM and users' login.
When the user first logs in, the `React` app obtains the session `id` and the csrf `token`. The app asks for the csrf token from the document cookies and that's the token used for later REST queries.

**Issue/Challenge:**
One of the app component allows a user to change the password.
 However, after a successful password change doing so, the session `id` and the csrf `token` become expired and the REST queries I do from that time on are unauthorized.

If I reload the page, after then, the session is expired. I tried to get the token again but it doesn't work.

**Question:**

- How can I update the session `id` after changing the password?
- Should I just send the user outside the app for them to log in again?

I don't know if that is the common way to proceded.

Below is the function that I use to get the token:

```js
getCookie(name) {
    console.log(name);

    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
      const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
      for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i += 1) {
        const cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (`${name}=`)) {
          cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(cookieValue);
    this.setState({
      token: cookieValue,
    });

//getCookie('csrftoken')
```

I don't usually work with cookies, apart from getting the csrf `token`, so I would appreciate any help.

**Update**

I found the problem might be due to Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#session-invalidation-on-password-change

As I am changing the password with Django Rest Framework -- following this tutorial: https://medium.com/django-rest/django-rest-framework-change-password-and-update-profile-1db0c144c0a3 -- I used the function `update_session_auth_hash` in the serializer as follows:

```
## serializer
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        instance.save()

        request = self.context['request']
        user = request.user
        update_session_auth_hash(request, user)
             
        return instance
```

I doesn't work either...

Comment: Most sites require a new login after changing the users password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work by using `instance` instead of `user`:

```
## serializer
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        instance.save()

        request = self.context['request']
        update_session_auth_hash(request, instance)
             
        return instance
```